# Elastic search duplicate aggregation section in a query with NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am creating a simple elastic request with Nest.

```
 var searchRequest = new SearchRequest()
    {
        Aggregations = new AggregationDictionary()
        {

        }
    };
```

When I serialize the query with `elasticClient.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(searchRequest` the query I am seeing like this :

```
{"aggs":{},"aggregations":{}}
```

Aggregation sections were created two times.

What should I do?

Is this a problem?

My nest version and elastic Search version are 7.6.2

Thanks.

Comment: You dont es class object on client side? It s better to dodge lowlevel query if you can.

Comment: I need to use it like this.